# Воспроизвести все возможные состояния потока java

Tags: java

Нужно написать приложение, которое выведет в консоль все возможные состояния потока в java, то есть вывод должен быть такой

```
 NEW
 RUNNABLE
 BLOCKED
 WAITING
 TIMED_WAITING
 TERMINATED
```

Очень плохо понимаю мультипоточность, особенно всякие мониторы с мьютексами. Смог написать только нечто подобное

Поток, который умрёт через секунду.

```
public class SomeThread implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getState()+ " runnable");
    try {
        sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Поток, который всегда в ожидании(я так и не смог его разбудить, пытался делать `static` переменную и применять `notify` из `main`, на что получал `IllegalMonitorStateException`)

```
public class SlowThread implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Object a = new Object();
        synchronized (a) {
                a.wait();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Основной класс

```
public class StatesStart {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new SomeThread());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new SlowThread());
        System.out.println(thread.getState() + " new");
        thread.start();
        thread2.start();
        sleep(500);
        System.out.println(thread.getState() + " timed_waiting");
        System.out.println(thread2.getState() + " waiting");
        sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(thread.getState() + " terminated");

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Пока что удалось получить 5 состояний из 6, как можно получить `BLOCKED`?

Comment: Если написать `synchronized(a){a.notify();}`, то ошибки выдавать не должно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря [Miron](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/337682/miron), я внёс нижеописанные изменения и получил все состояния потока в java

Тут добавил статический объект и написал к нему геттер

```
public class SlowThread implements Runnable {

public static Object getA() {
    return a;
}

private static Object a = new Object();
@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        synchronized (a) {
                a.wait();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

А в главный класс добавил `synchronized` блок, без него выкидывает исключение(как я понял из-за того, что мы не захватываем монитор(объект?) для работы и его могут перехватить)
Тоже не очень почему, но монитор всё ещё заблокирован и следующая строчка выводит сообщение о том, что поток заблокирован. Впрочем, через 2 секунды узнаём, что поток всё-таки разбудили через `notify` и он благополучно завершился.

```
System.out.println(thread2.getState() + " waiting");

        Object a = SlowThread.getA();
        synchronized (a){
            a.notify();
        }

        System.out.println(thread2.getState() + " blocked");
        sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(thread2.getState() + " terminated thread 2");
```